# Volume control hidden

Tags: mediaelement.js

On my wordpress site i'm using an accordion plugin and inside it is my code for mediaelementjs audio. My problem is when click on the volume, the volume control is hidden behind the accordion. Here's a screenshot:
http://i54.tinypic.com/35isyyt.png

and here's the url: http://goo.gl/qmZoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with ID `thethe-accordion-content-1` has its `overflow` CSS property set to `auto`. You need to set it to `visible` instead. Something like that might work:

```
#thethe-accordion-content-1 {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, setting it to visible worked. Can you tell me what's wrong with overflow and why it worked when visible is used? :)

Comment: `overflow: auto` means that if the div is not big enough, the content inside is going to be clipped. Setting it to visible, means that it's visible whether the div is too small or not.